# Neo4J Cypher: Match ()-[]-() Return count(*) return double of the number of the relationships when node labels are not assigned

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my database, there is a kind of relationships between `A` and `B` named `awithb`.
For the Cypher

```
MATCH ()-[:awithb]-() return count(*)
```

it returns 140.

However if we give the labels of the node,

```
MATCH (:A)-[:awithb]-(:B) return count(*)
```

it returns 70.

Why these two cypher queries return different results?

Comment: Without labels, isn't it possible that either node could match either side of the relationship? You don't specify any directionality, nor type of node per side...

Answer (score 1):

Cypher is about returning paths that match patterns.

Paths are **ordered** sequences of nodes and relationships, and when no direction is specified, and no labels are specified, then a pattern like that will produce two paths using the same relationship and the same two nodes, just the order of the nodes in the path is different, and you traverse the relationship in the other direction.

If you add a direction to the pattern, then only one path is possible:

```
MATCH ()-[:awithb]->() 
RETURN count(*)
```

Comment: Thanks! Does this means that `MATCH (:A)-[:awithb]-(:B) return count(*)` and `MATCH (:A)-[:awithb]->(:B) return count(*)`  return the same results?

Comment: Not necessarily. If relationships were created that pointed toward the :A nodes then the counts would not match. All relationships in Neo4j are directed. If the direction matters to you, then you can include it in your MATCH pattern, otherwise omitting the direction will match to rels going in either direction.

Answer (score 1):

When you put no labels on your query, it means that you want ANY nodes that have that relationship.

```
 () - [: awithb] - ()  where () is any nodes
```

When you put non-directional path with corresponding labels; it means the relationship can be from A to B or B to A.

```
 (:A) - [: awithb] - (:B) equals  A->B  OR  A<-B
```

Thus, in your first query, you are getting 2x the counts because you are getting the path  from A to B and B to A.